# Hadoop: Easy way to have object as output value without Writable interface

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop, weka

I am trying to exploit hadoop to train multiple models . My data are small enough to fit in memory so i want to have one model trained in every map task.

My problem is that when i have finished training my model, i need to send it to the reducer. I am using Weka to train the model. I don't want to start looking how to implement the Writable interface in Weka classes, because it needs a lot of effort. I am looking for a simple way to do this.

The Classifier class in Weka implements the Serializable interface. How can i send this object to the reducer?

```
        edits
```

Here is the link that mentions weka objects serialization: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization

Here is what my code looks like:
Configuring the job(only a part of the configuration is posted):

```
       conf.set("io.serializations","org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization," + "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization"); 
       job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
       job.setOutputValueClass(Classifier.class);
```

Map function:

```
     //load dataset in data variable
     Classifier tree=new J48();
     tree.buildClassifier();
     context.write(new Text("whatever"), tree);
```

My Map class extends Mapper (Object,Text,Text,Classifier)

But i am getting this error:

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerializer(SerializationFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:964)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:673)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:369)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
```

What i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your own serialization mechanism

- http://www.lexemetech.com/2008/07/rpc-and-serialization-with-hadoop.html
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1986

I think it resolves around implementing the Serialization interface, and defining your implementation in the `io.serializations` configuration property

In your case, if you just want to use java serialization, set this property to:

- `org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization`

Comment: Ohh thanks..I will check it out today and post any further questions.

Comment: Text definitely doesn't implement Serializable so hadoop doesn't know how to deal with this type - you can use both Java and hadoop serialization together - set `io.serializations` to `org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization,org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization`

Comment: this is what i have done.see the code i posted in the configuration section.

Comment: http://www.sourcepod.com/uujpdz77-7029 . If you checked the weka serialization link i posted, you will see that they have posted source code for saving classifiers as objects. So the serialization must work fine

Comment: http://www.sourcepod.com/bucnin48-7030 . This is the abstract classifier class that implements classifier

Comment: Ok, it's doing the lookup based upon the class you define in the job.setOutputValueClass() - so if Classifier.class doesn't implement Serializable or Writable, your going to see your error. Amend the call to setOutputValueClass to name a specific instance (J48.class if all output is this type, or AbstractClassifier.class to be more generic)

Comment: Thanks for you help and interest. What you said has to be the solution. I tried it but i am getting Type mismatch in value from map: expected weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier, recieved weka.classifiers.trees.J48 error. This is error has no meaning at all, since J48 extends AbstractClassifier. I managed to find that weka has a class SerializedObject that manages serialization and i think it worked (still have to do some tests). What you said though is far more "right" than what i accidentally found.

Comment: Hadoop doesn't write out the type for each key and value pair stored in a sequence file, it stores the type you declared at the top of the seq file. If you want to have multiple types output, you need to implement something like hadoop's GenericWritable, but for Serializable objects