# How to serialize an Java Object in Hadoop?

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop

Object should implement `Writable` interface in order to be serialized when transmitted in Hadoop. Take the Lucene `ScoreDoc` class as an example:

```
public class ScoreDoc implements java.io.Serializable {

  /** The score of this document for the query. */
  public float score;

  /** Expert: A hit document's number.
   * @see Searcher#doc(int) */
  public int doc;

  /** Only set by {@link TopDocs#merge} */
  public int shardIndex;

  /** Constructs a ScoreDoc. */
  public ScoreDoc(int doc, float score) {
    this(doc, score, -1);
  }

  /** Constructs a ScoreDoc. */
  public ScoreDoc(int doc, float score, int shardIndex) {
    this.doc = doc;
    this.score = score;
    this.shardIndex = shardIndex;
  }

  // A convenience method for debugging.
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "doc=" + doc + " score=" + score + " shardIndex=" + shardIndex;
  }
}
```

How should I serialize it with `Writable` interface? What is the connection between `Writable` and `java.io.serializable` interface?

Comment: Just to clarify... why exactly would you need to transfer instances of `ScoreDoc` directly in hadoop (and not wrapped as one of the answer suggests) ? Can you provide a bit more details on your use-case ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it wont be a good idea to tamper with the in-built Lucene class. Instead, have your own class which can will contain the fields of ScoreDoc type and would implement Hadoop writable in interface. It would be something like this:

```
public class MyScoreDoc implements Writable  {      

  private ScoreDoc sd;

  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
      String [] splits = sd.toString().split(" ");

      // get the score value from the string
      Float score = Float.parseFloat((splits[0].split("="))[1]);

      // do the same for doc and shardIndex fields
      // ....    

      out.writeInt(score);
      out.writeInt(doc);
      out.writeInt(shardIndex);
  }

  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
      float score = in.readInt();
      int doc = in.readInt();
      int shardIndex = in.readInt();

      sd = new ScoreDoc (score, doc, shardIndex);
  }

  //String toString()
}
```

Comment: What's the internal difference between the two approaches when hadoop passes the value between mappers and reducers?

Comment: @Denzel: In short, the main difference would be that one will work while the other will not (since hadoop relies on the `Writable` interface for wire transfer) :)

Comment: It uses Writable to optimally send data across the network.

Answer (score 0):

First see [Hadoop: Easy way to have object as output value without Writable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913626/hadoop-easy-way-to-have-object-as-output-value-without-writable-interface?rq=1) you can use Java serialization OR

See http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html you need to make your own write and read function, its quite simple as inside can call the API to read and write int, flaot, string etc

Your example with Writable (need to import it)

```
public class ScoreDoc implements java.io.Serializable, Writable  {      
    /** The score of this document for the query. */
    public float score;//... as in above

  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
      out.writeInt(score);
      out.writeInt(doc);
      out.writeInt(shardIndex);
  }

  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
      score = in.readInt();
      doc = in.readInt();
      shardIndex = in.readInt();    
  }

  //rest toStirng etc
}
```

Note : order of write and read should be the same or value of one will go to other, and if you have different types will get serialization errors on read