# Serialization of an object in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce

we have an object as following,

[user_id,name,email,password]

1- How can we serialize this object?
2- How can we serialize user_id,name,email part only?
That means I dnt want serialize password field.

Comment: You start by doing some research on your own. Seriously: this is really basic stuff, and it is document a zillion times out there. Don't expect us to **teach** you such things.

Comment: I think you are asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837640/how-to-serialize-an-java-object-in-hadoop

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836607/what-are-the-connections-and-differences-between-hadoop-writable-and-java-io-ser/16839597#16839597

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare password field as transient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectOutputStream` and tag the class to be `java.io.Serializable` and mark the `password` field `transient`

### The class

```
public class Xample implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String user_id;
    private String nameString ;
    private String email;
    private transient String password;

    public Xample(String user_id, String nameString, String email, String password) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.nameString = nameString;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

### Serialisation

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Xample xample = new Xample("9898ddsk", "billy", "billy@work.com", "$ecret");

    // as an example i am using memory for the sink (ByteArrayOutputStream)
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bao);
    oos.writeObject(xample);

}
```